# 2D array Similarity

Tags: algorithm, matrix

I am given two 2-dimensional arrays each of size N*N .Two 2D sub arrays of these arrays are said to be similar if atleast K% elements of these subarrays are having same value and same position in both arrays . I need to tell the maximum size of such subarray and the number of such subarrays having this maximum size.

Please help to solve this problem

Example:

Suppose i have two 2d arrays and k=50:

---

1 3 5

6 7 8

5 7 9

---

1 5 7

6 7 3

3 7 9

---

Here , we can see we have out of all submatrices 2 submtracies of 2*2 that are :

1. A

   1 3

   6 7

   B

   1 5

   6 7
2. A

   7 8

   7 9

   B

   7 3

   7 9

Both these submatrices are having three elements in common,and clearly more than 50 % elements are same.And also the position of both submatrices is also same

But the 3*3 matrix itself has more than 50 % elements same.
So the answer will be max size is 3 and number of submatrices is 1

Comment: That sounds like a homework problem.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I know a basic naive approach to check for all possible submatrices.But it is very inefficient.I want some better and efficient algorithm for this.And by the way its not any homework

Comment: Can you explain the problem more briefly. Preferably with an example.

Comment: What do you mean by maximum size of subarray in the 2D context? Is it n*m or n+m or max(n,m)? Or are you looking for a square sub-matrix?

Comment: @ abhishek @ nishu Tried to explain it by above example

Comment: What is your naive solution?  Is it based on iterating over submatrices or creating hashtables of the contents?  Also, does the submatrix have to be smaller size than the parent?  In your example the two top level matrices have 5 elements in common, so the maximum would seem to be 3x3.  Also, do the submatrices have to be square?

Comment: @Jherico firstly the submatrix can be equal to parent also and i had edited it to 3*3.and they need to be square for sure.and my naive approach is based on iterating over all submatrices

Answer (score 1):

Using these two matrices(A, B), form a third matrix (C)that has an element:

```
C(i,j) = { 1 if A(i,j) == B(i,j), else zero}
```

Now the problem is to find the largest submatrix in C that has atleast k% 1s. So if the submatrix is of size mxm, then:

```
Sum of all elements in this submatrix >= (k/100) *m*m.
```

This can be done in O(N^3) time as follows:

For each element, calculate the cummulative sum of all elements before it.

```
D(i,j) = summation ( C(l,h) for l = 0 to i and h = 0 to j )
```

Now the possible sizes of submatrices can be (nxn) down to (1x1). So for each size (s) matrix from n to 1, loop through the submatrices.

This can be done with 1 pointer p that scans each element and forms the top left corner of the sub-matrix. The top right corner q of submatrix shall be in the same row as p but with a column at p + s.

You can check the sum of elements in submatrix formed by p and q as topleft and topright corners respectively in O(1) time since you know the cumulative sum upto the elements.

```
Sum of elements in sub-matrix(p->q) for row r 
  = D( r + q - p, q ) - D( r-1, q ) - D( r + q - p, p - 1 ) + D ( r - 1, p - 1 )
```

Stop when you find a valid matrix or multiple valid matrices of same size.

Comment: D(i,j) = summation ( C(l,h) for l = 0 to i and h = 0 to j ) here how is it O(n^3) wont it be o(n^4).?

Comment: @user3080139 No it will not be. I leave that for you to figure out how.

Comment: The complexity for building the matrix D shall be only O(N^2). Hint: To calculate D(i,j) use the values for D(i-1,j) etc that have already been calculated.

Comment: No. As stated, D(i,j) is storing the sum of ALL elements that come before it. So D(N,N) shall be the sum of all the elements in the matrix.

Comment: Are you keeping check that i need only square submatrices?

Comment: @user3080139 Please read the algorithm carefully. I don't think you have understood the basic idea behind it.

Answer (score 0):

My first pass would be to generate a boolean matrix of the same size as your two inputs, with true meaning the value match at that position, and false meaning they don't.  Then I'd find the the smallest square submatrix where the number of trues over the total values exceeds K, starting with the total matrix and then working my way down.  Is that what you're doing now?

EDIT:

It seems like the search for the solution in the boolean matrix is an application of [density-based clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis#Density-based_clustering).  Perhaps an adaptation of the [DBSCAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) algorithm is possible.  It claims to be either O(n LOG n) or O(N^2) depending on whether an indexing structure is used.

Comment: Ya..but its too time consuming algorithm